# How to disable white text color in selection in view-based NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm using a view-based table view and don't want it to draw NSTextFields with white text color when it is selected.
I was not able to find a working solution. So any help is very appreciated.

Here is my problem:

[image]

I want the "Selection is white" text also be drawn in the default text color.

So far I figured out that

- Setting attributes in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:item:` does not really help
- Setting `NSTextField` color to a custom color, which is something different than the control default color, will prevent from drawing in white but it still looses font style (bold, italic, etc).
- Setting `NSTableView`'s `selectionHighlightStyle` attribute to `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` does the trick but it will not redraw `NSTableRowView`. Also the select style is not what I want. I want the first click to select the row and the second click to edit the text field. When you use `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` your first click starts editing the text field.
- The text color does not change if the NSTextField is bordered. But I don't want bordered text fields (As shown in the screenshot. The  text fields are editable)

I couldn't figure out 'how' the text field gets the white color. I have overridden `setTextColor:` and realized that it is never called when selection is changed. So I guess an NSAttributedString is built somewhere inside the NSTableView drawing/selecting routine.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to subclass `NSTableCellView` and override `setBackgroundStyle:`. That's all!

```
- (void)setBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)backgroundStyle {
  [super setBackgroundStyle: NSBackgroundStyleLight];
}
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I just "disabled" setter. For swift it is: `override var backgroundStyle: NSBackgroundStyle { get { return .Dark } set { } }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding `NSTableCellView`'s `backgroundStyle`, I found it more convenient to override `viewWillDraw()` in `NSTableRowView` instead. This is actually the method that by default changes your cell view's background style during selection.

You would disable this behavior by:

```swift
class TableViewDelegate: NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
        return TableRowView(frame: NSRect.zero)
    }
}

class TableRowView : NSTableRowView {
    private override func viewWillDraw() {
        // By do nothing we prevent the super method to be called. It would otherwise change the selected cell view's backgroundStyle property.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I set cell colour in my table view delegate's -tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row: method.

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell 
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
   if(tableView==<table view id of interest>)
      {
      ...
      [cell setTextColor:<colour appropriate for this cell>];
      ...
      }
   ...
}
```

This does not affect font size or styling.

Comment: How are they working differently? If you're using `NSTableView` or a subclass then if your controller object adopts the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol it gets the above message selector. I use exactly this technique to selectively grey-out entries in a table when they are inapplicable in a given context. I simply call `[tableViewId setDelegate:self]` in my controller's `awakeFromNib:` method and bingo.

Comment: cell-based tables and view-based tables work differently.  You are using a cell-based table `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` will never be called if you were using view-based tables. Hey, thank you though for trying to help.